# Apple Authentication Button doesn't show up using expo-apple-authentication package

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to implement Apple Sign In in my iOS app using the [expo-apple-authentication](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-apple-authentication) package, but I'm not being able to make the button show up. Even though I'm using the exact same code as the documentation:

```
 <AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButton
   buttonType={
     AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonType.SIGN_IN
   }
   buttonStyle={
     AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonStyle.BLACK
   }
   cornerRadius={5}
   onPress={() => {
   }}
 />
```

It's worth noticing that the call to AppleAuthentication.isAvailableAsync() returns true.

I'm testing it in a Simulator. Is it not supposed to work in a dev environment? how am I supposed to test it then?

Answer (score 6):

For some odd reason the button does not have a default size. Applying your own style fixes it.

```
<AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButton
  onPress={onSignIn}
  buttonType={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonType.SIGN_IN}
  buttonStyle={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonStyle.BLACK}
  style={{ width: 200, height: 64 }} // You must choose default size
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

expo-apple-authentication provides Apple authentication for iOS 13+. It does not yet support lower iOS versions, Android, or web.

May be your emulator has an older version.